# Error when showing x amount of result for a Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've never heard of this but it happens here:

I have a dataframe generated through sqlContext.sql operation in Scala.
Presumably there should be 12 records as shown in its mysql data source.

When I use:

```
result.show(7)
```

7 results are shown up normally;
When I use:

```
result.show(8)
```

I received the following error:

> 18/03/05 21:02:48 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split:
>   hdfs://nn01.itversity.com:8020/user/paslechoix/products/part-m-00000:0+86996
>   18/03/05 21:02:48 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_20_piece0
>   on localhost:42892 in memory (size: 2008.0 B, free: 511.1 MB) 18/03/05
>   21:02:48 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 19.0 (TID 22)
>   **java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String**
>           at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
>           at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)

It would be greatly appreciated if someone can tell me what's wrong here?

The expected result from mysql is as below for your reference:

```
    mysql> select * from products where product_name like 'Per%';
+------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| product_id | product_category_id | product_name                               | product_description | product_price | product_image                                                              |
+------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|        362 |                  17 | Perfect Fitness Perfect Ab Strap Pro       |                     |         29.99 | http://images.acmesports.sports/Perfect+Fitness+Perfect+Ab+Strap+Pro       |
|        365 |                  17 | Perfect Fitness Perfect Rip Deck           |                     |         59.99 | http://images.acmesports.sports/Perfect+Fitness+Perfect+Rip+Deck           |
|        372 |                  17 | Perfect Ab Carver Pro                      |                     |         39.99 | http://images.acmesports.sports/Perfect+Ab+Carver+Pro                      |
|        373 |                  17 | Perfect Fitness Multi Gym Pro              |                     |         39.99 | http://images.acmesports.sports/Perfect+Fitness+Multi+Gym+Pro              |
|        374 |                  17 | Perfect Pushup BASIC                       |                     |         19.99 | http://images.acmesports.sports/Perfect+Pushup+BASIC                       |
|        376 |                  17 | Perfect Pushup V2 Performance              |                     |         29.99 | http://images.acmesports.sports/Perfect+Pushup+V2+Performance              |
|        377 |                  17 | Perfect Pullup Basic                       |                     |         19.99 | http://images.acmesports.sports/Perfect+Pullup+Basic                       |
|        379 |                  17 | Perfect Multi-Gym - As Seen on TV!         |                     |         29.99 | http://images.acmesports.sports/Perfect+Multi-Gym+-+As+Seen+on+TV%21       |
|       1013 |                  46 | Perception Sport Swifty Deluxe 9.5 Kayak   |                     |        349.99 | http://images.acmesports.sports/Perception+Sport+Swifty+Deluxe+9.5+Kayak   |
|       1030 |                  46 | Perception Sport Striker 11.5 Angler Kayak |                     |        499.99 | http://images.acmesports.sports/Perception+Sport+Striker+11.5+Angler+Kayak |
|       1065 |                  48 | Perception Sport Swifty Deluxe 9.5 Kayak   |                     |        349.99 | http://images.acmesports.sports/Perception+Sport+Swifty+Deluxe+9.5+Kayak   |
|       1093 |                  49 | Perception Sport Swifty Deluxe 9.5 Kayak   |                     |        349.99 | http://images.acmesports.sports/Perception+Sport+Swifty+Deluxe+9.5+Kayak   |
+------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If I run the script below:

```
val results12 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM products") 
results12.show()
```

It returns default 20 records with no error.

If you need extra info from the error, let me know and I will post the full error message. Thank you very much.

Update 1:

If I do:

```
val result2 = sqlContext.sql("select * from products where productID = 379")
result2.show(1)
```

I receive the following error:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

So it seems 379 is causing the problem.

I continue with 377, same error message when `show(1)`.

However I don't understand that 377 is included in result1:

```
val result1 = sqlContext.sql("select * from products where name like 'Per%'")

scala> result1.show(7)

+---------+-----------+--------------------+--------+-----+--------------------+
|productID|productCode|                name|quantity|price|               image|
+---------+-----------+--------------------+--------+-----+--------------------+
|      362|         17|Perfect Fitness P...|        |29.99|http://images.acm...|
|      365|         17|Perfect Fitness P...|        |59.99|http://images.acm...|
|      372|         17|Perfect Ab Carver...|        |39.99|http://images.acm...|
|      373|         17|Perfect Fitness M...|        |39.99|http://images.acm...|
|      374|         17|Perfect Pushup BASIC|        |19.99|http://images.acm...|
|      376|         17|Perfect Pushup V2...|        |29.99|http://images.acm...|
|      377|         17|Perfect Pullup Basic|        |19.99|http://images.acm...|
+---------+-----------+--------------------+--------+-----+--------------------+
only showing top 7 rows
```

Comment: There's a `{}` button to turn a piece of text into a code block (by indenting by four), which works much better for both the SQL output and the error traceback.

Comment: While you're editing your question, don't forget to add one or two more useful tags to it.

Comment: Try to reduce your problem to finding the one row causing the problem (assuming it's one row), then look at the error message, look at the row, see if either makes sense.

Comment: Thank you Evert.

Comment: Much nicer, ty. Two quick questions to try and trim the problem down a bit further:

Comment: 1/ What if you do `val result2 = sqlContext.sql("select * from products where productID = 379"); result2.show()`. So remove the `1` from `show()`, but stick to a single row. Does that cause any errors?

Comment: 2/ What if you select single (or a few) columns for that row. E.g. `val result2 = sqlContext.sql("select productID, productCode from products where productID = 379");`? Perhaps that way, you can even nail it to a single offending column, and thus to a single offending cell.

Comment: I've added a few tags, and remove the dataframe tag (that felt too generic: R, Python-Pandas and tons of other languages/frameworks have dataframes too). Correct them if the tags are incorrect (sqlContext seems to be related to Spark, but I'm not sure).

Comment: val result2 = sqlContext.sql("select * from products where productID = 379"); -----no error; result2.show() ----same error; select less columns is a good point, but still fails on show() and show(1)

Comment: For the convenience, here is the data file: https://github.com/mdivk/175Scala/blob/master/data/part-m-00000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved this issue.

In the original data, there are records with price column is empty, not null.

So when the data is converted to RDD, it errors out already due to **p.split(",")(4).toFloat** in the command below:

```
val prdRDD = prd.map(p=>(p.split(",")(0).toInt, p.split(",")(1), p.split(",")(2), p.split(",")(3), p.split(",")(4).toFloat,p.split(",")(5)))
```

The solution is to rewrite the prdRDD to:

```
val prdRDD = prd.map(p=>p.split(",")).map(p=>(p(0).toInt, p(1), p(2), p(3), { if( p(4)==null ||  p(4)=="" ) p(4)=0 else p(4).toFloat },p(5)))
```

This way ensures p(4) can be converted into Float.

After that the whole script is working as expected.

Thank you all for the enlightening.